# Add animation listener for an alert dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an alert dialog and I use a custom animation on entry:

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.my_animation;  
<style name="my_animation">  
  <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slider_anim</item>    
</style>  

R.anim.slider_anim.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fromXDelta="-100%p"  
           android:fromYDelta="0"  
           android:duration=“1500">

</translate>
```

This works fine but I can’t figure out how to set an animation listener to detect the end of the animation. I need to animate another view *after* the dialog’s animation is done.
I tried this but the animation is not loading at all:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(root.getContext(), R.anim.slider_anim);     
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  

    }  

    @Override  
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {  
      Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {  

    }  
});  
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setAnimation(animation);
```

How can I do this?